# Kivy - Problem with widgets being added to a screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have one screen that's a 'Loading' screen and it plays an animation while threaded functions performs tasks in the background. It might be worth mentioning that the animation itself is also threaded. Once the threaded function (that isn't the animation) is done it switches screens to the 'Result' screen. The Result Screen then populates its GridLayout widget with widgets called 'Basers'. These Baser widgets are produced from a loop inside the python code since the number of widgets produced and information they show and hold depend on the result from the threaded function that ran during the Loading Screen.

.py code:

```
class ResultBackBtn(FloatLayout):
    pass

#The Screen with the problem
class ScreenResult(Screen):

     def trytest(self):
        print('hello')

     def ScreenChR(self, *args):
         self.manager.switch_to(ScreenHome(name="Home"))

#The layout for the animation on ScreenLoading
class Loader(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loader, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x=50
        self.selfo = False
        self.button=Button(text='move',size_hint=(0.2,0.05),pos=(self.x,200))
        self.add_widget(self.button)
        Tpool.apply_async(self.animate2)

    def animate2(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.animate, 0.01)

    def animate(self,*args):
        if self.x==600:
            self.selfo = True
            self.x-=10
        elif self.x==50:
            self.selfo = False
            self.x+=10
        else:
            if self.selfo == True:
                self.x-=10
            elif self.selfo == False:
                self.x+=10
        self.button.pos[0]=self.x

#The Loading screen where the threaded functions are also executed - this happens in the ThreadPool 'Tpool'
class ScreenLoading(Screen):
    global Tpool
    Tpool = ThreadPool(processes=3)
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.add_widget(Loader())
        Tpool.apply_async(self.mainProcessTry)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        print('on_leave')
        self.resultStart()
        return super().on_leave(*args)

    #This the defined function that should generate the 'Baser' widgets. The placement might seem weird, but I've moved it everywhere to see if it could get fixed
    def resultStart(self):
        print('widgeting')
        print(self)
        bello = self.manager.get_screen('Result').ids.Grid1
        for n in range(0, len(resultDict)):
            print('widget added')
            bello.add_widget(Baser(AlName=resultDict[n]['al_name'], ArtName=resultDict[n]['art_name'], formatsI=resultDict[n]['formats'], yearI=resultDict[n]['year'], smallImage=resultDict[n]['small_image_link'], releaseID=resultDict[n]['release_code']))

    #The 'main' threaded function that produces the 'resultDict' dictionary that the 'Baser' widgets are based on
    def mainProcessTry(self, *args):
        // Function from another file - returns resultDict //
        print('resultDict length', len(resultDict))
        print('should switch screens...')
        self.manager.current = 'Result'

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# The python declaration of the 'Baser' widget
class Baser(FloatLayout):
    AlName = StringProperty('')
    ArtName = StringProperty('')
    formatsI = StringProperty('')
    yearI = StringProperty('')
    smallImage = StringProperty('')
    releaseID = StringProperty('')
    
    #This function is activated if the 'Baser' widget is clicked 
    def Pressbtn(self, instance):
        global selectedResult
        selectedResult = instance.releaseIO
        with open('RecentLog.json', 'r') as recentfile:
            userRecent = json.load(recentfile)
        userRecent2 = userRecent
        for ut in resultDict:
            if ut['release_code'] == selectedResult:
                choseSelect = ut
        userRecent2.insert(0, choseSelect)
        userRecent3 = userRecent2[:6]
        with open('RecentLog.json', 'w') as recentfile2:
            json.dump(userRecent3, recentfile2)
        #with open('UserLog.json', 'w') as userfile2:
            #json.dump(userDB, userfile2)
        #userRecent['recents'][:5]
        self.parent.parent.parent.parent.manager.switch_to(finalResultScreen(name="finalResults"))
#the 'finalResults' screen shows information from the Baser widget after it's been clicked on by the User

class AttemptApp(App):
    lloop = HomeTab

    def LoginPopup(self):
            with open('UserLog.json', 'r') as userfile:
                userDB = json.load(userfile)
            userDB['userPopup'] = False
            with open('UserLog.json', 'w') as userfile2:
                json.dump(userDB, userfile2)

    def UserLogin(self):
            with open('UserLog.json', 'r') as userfile:
                userDB = json.load(userfile)
            userDB['userLogin'] = True
            userDB['userPopup'] = False
            with open('UserLog.json', 'w') as userfile2:
                json.dump(userDB, userfile2)
    def build(self):
         return Builder.load_file('Attempt.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AttemptApp().run()
```

.kv code:

```
#The Layout and structure for the repeated 'Baser' widget
<Baser@FloatLayout>:
    height: "100dp"
    width: "828dp"
    al: root.AlName
    art: root.ArtName
    source: root.smallImage
    formatsI: root.formatsI
    yearI: root.yearI
    releaseIO: root.releaseID
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (.87,.44, .24, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [(40, 40), (40, 40), (40, 40), (40, 40)]
    AsyncImage:
        fit_mode: "contain"
        pos: self.parent.pos
        pos_hint: {"x":-0.08,"y":0.1}
        size: self.texture_size
        size_hint: (.53, .8)
        source: root.source

    Label:
        #Al name
        pos: self.parent.pos
        pos_hint: {"x":.18, "y":.58}
        text: root.al
        shorten: True
        shorten_from: "right"
        text_size: ((self.parent.width / 100) * 60, (self.parent.height / 100) * 80)
        size: self.text_size
        font_size: 45
        halign: "left"

    Label:
        #Art
        pos: self.parent.pos
        pos_hint: {"x":.18, "y":.3}
        text: root.art
        shorten: True
        shorten_from: "right"
        text_size: ((self.parent.width / 100) * 60, (self.parent.height / 100) * 80)
        size: self.text_size
        font_size: 45
        halign: "left"

    Label:
        #Format + Date 
        pos: self.parent.pos
        pos_hint: {"x":.18, "y":.03}
        text: root.formatsI + ' • ' + root.yearI
        shorten: True
        shorten_from: "right"
        text_size: ((self.parent.width / 100) * 60, (self.parent.height / 100) * 80)
        size: self.text_size
        font_size: 45
        halign: "left"
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        size: self.parent.size
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 0.678, 0.133, 0.459, 0
        on_press:
            root.Pressbtn(root) 

# This is the screen where I'm experiencing problems 
<ScreenResult>:
    name: "Result"
    on_enter: app.resultStart()  #on_enter doesn't produce any results in both .py and .kv file
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            scroll_wheel_distance: "50dp"
            GridLayout:
                id: Grid1
                cols: 1
                row_force_default: True
                foo: [self.rows_minimum.update({i: x.height}) for i, x in     enumerate(reversed(list(self.children)))]
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: 1
                size_hint_y: 1
                ResultBackBtn:    #a predefined button design. Wouldn't get added to Result layout unless it was placed in .kv file

<ResultBackBtn>:  #predefined button - visible at the top of the image provided
    height: "50dp"
    width: "835dp"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,0,0,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Image:
        fit_mode: "contain"
        source: "logos/LogoFullName.png"
        size: 300, 70
        size_hint: None,None
        pos: self.parent.pos
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}

    Button:
        text: "Back"
        font_size: 20
        pos: self.parent.pos
        size_hint: (.2, 1)
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: .7,.7,.7,1
        on_press: self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.ScreenChR()

#This is the screen with the Loading animation 
<ScreenLoading>:
    name: "Loading"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            BorderImage:
                source: 'backgrounds/background.png'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

#This is the layout for the animation that's present in the above 'ScreenLoading' screen
<Loader>:
    pos_hint: {"x_center":.5,"y_center":.5}
    size_hint: 1, 1
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,0
```

The 'ScreenResults' screen contains a GridLayout inside a ScrollView. This GridLayout (id = Grid1) is coded to adjust its height to the number of widgets placed inside it. Strangely I actually got the screens to function and produce the result I wanted by removing the Loading animation, removing any Threading so the screen freezes while the function runs, and it worked perfectly! The issue is I want that animation to be there, so I don't want to go with the easy option in this case.

### What I've tried so far:

- Moving the function that add's the 'Baser' widgets to the GridLayout (called 'resultStart()' in 'ScreenLoading' in the code provided) to the ScreenResult's 'on_enter' function. I tried this on both .py and .kv but neither produced results. I put print functions in the function's code to see if it at least started - nothing was printed which gave me the conclusion that the on_enter function was called at all. I also moved this function to the App class and called it from there. I've moved it everywhere, changing the 'where.what.who.add_widget()' each time - and nothing worked at all.
- I tried giving different part's of the screen their own classes - such as the GridLayout, Scrollview, FloatLayout, and so on - no change
- I tried calling the function in the main threaded function before `self.manager.current = 'Result'` was called. This caused the screen not to change, as if it gave up on the function?

[image: A screenshot of the loading screen (ScreenLoading). The animation I mentioned is the box with the text 'move' which is moving back-and-fourth horizontally]

[image: A Screenshot of the 'Result' screen where I'm facing the problems. The black bar at the top is the ResultBackBtn that can be seen in the code. Note there's an image beside the 'Back' button, however I've blacked it out for privacy reasons.]

The Grey area show in the second screenshot, below the black bar, is where the 'Baser' widgets should be.

Any and all help will be much appreciated as this is a problem I've been facing for about 4 days now. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Also sorry for the massive images - I'm not sure how to scale them down

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but if you are running this on windows, then your `Attempt.kv` file will get loaded twice. Once by your `build()` method and once by the `App` class. I suggest changing the `kv` file name to something unrelated to your `App` name to see if that is part of the problem.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks for your response! I'm afraid I'm using macOS, but I'll try it anyway! Better to be safe than sorry